# Using custom Maven version in Jenkins on OpenShift

Tags: maven, jenkins, openshift

I'm trying to run maven-android-sdk-deployer on my OpenShift Jenkins. It needs at least Maven 3.1.1 to run, whereas OpenShift currently uses version 3.0.5 as default. Thus I tried to configure a custom Maven installation.

**My Maven system configuration:**

- name: maven-3.1.1
- install automatically: true
- one installer with "Unzip archive" (I also tried "Install from Apache" with the same result.)

  - label: empty
  - download url: http://mirror.synyx.de/apache/maven/maven-3/3.1.1/binaries/apache-maven-3.1.1-bin.zip
  - subfolder in archive: apache-maven-3.1.1

It seems to install Maven, because there is another error message, if "subfolder in archive" doesn't match. The zip file is valid.

**But I cannot use it in the job.**

I created a freestyle job and added a Maven step with the configured Maven installation.

There is an error message, when running the job:

```
[maven-android-sdk-deployer] $ app-root/data/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-3.1.1/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn install -P 4.1
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "app-root/data/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-3.1.1/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn" (in directory "app-root/data/jenkins/workspace/maven-android-sdk-deployer"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    ... 17 more
```

**Workaround for command line**

I checked the file system the `maven-android-sdk-deployer` workspace and `app-root/data/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-3.1.1/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn` both exist on the myappbldr-gear.

When I run the command from commandline I get the same error, whereas **appending `~/`** to the maven path **works as intended**:

`[maven-android-sdk-deployer] $ ~/app-root/data/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-3.1.1/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn install -P 4.1`

Looks like this is an administration problem. **How can I fix this?**

Comment: Can you check to make sure`app-root/data/jenkins/workspace/maven-android-sdk-deployer` exists on the gear? If not try making that directory manually and try the build once more.

Comment: ssh into your gear with `rhc ssh <yourappname>` then cd into app-root/data/jenkins/workspace/ and run an ls